# How to move code to data, becoming more Data Driven Approach?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine, command-pattern

For reference, please see article: https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/bytecode.html#data-%3E-code

Hello, I'm currently looking at a lot of repetition in my game code in C#,

as for example:

```
public void SomeAction() {
    DoSomething();
    DoSomething();
    DoAnotherThing();
}
```

I have managed to convert this code to data driven approach, using command pattern:

```
public List<Command> commands;

public void DoAction() {
    foreach (cmd in commands) {
        cmd.Execute();
    }
}
```

I have realized that Data driven approach is beautifully designed and it is the right approach for me.
But then I stumbled into this one:

```
private float[] data;

public IEnumerable<float> ExampleQuery() {
    return data
        .Select(x => x + 2)
        .Where(x => x < 50)
        .Select(x => x * 3)
        .Select(x => x * 10)
        .Select(x => x > 999 ? 999 : x);
}
```

how to convert to this:

```
private float[] data;
public List<Rules> rules;

public IEnumerable<float> Query() {
    // should I foreach here?
}
```

As you can see, this one should be data driven, so that if I want to make more rules for data query, I don't have to recompile and can just add more rules into the list.

From the reference:

> We want them to be easy to modify, easy to reload, and physically separate from the rest of the executable. 
>   **I don’t know about you, but to me that sounds a lot like data**. If we can define our behavior in separate data files that the game engine loads and “executes” in some way, we can achieve all of our goals. We just need to figure out what “execute” means for data.

I don't need to be all-out using bytecode pattern, I just want my rules to be hierarchy data, that is modeled using class/object, such as command pattern.

*Any good reference article will be a big help also.

Comment: Have you looked into expression trees in c#

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
public List<Rules> rules;
var floats = data.Select(x => x + 2)
        .Where(x => x < 50)
        .Select(x => x * 3)
        .Select(x => x * 10)
        .Select(x => x > 999 ? 999 : x);

public List<Rules> ExampleQuery()
{
 foreach(var d in floats)
 {
  rules.Add(d);
 }
  return rules;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the a list of functions like this:

```cs
List<( Func<float,bool> where, Func<float,float> select )> rules;

public IEnumerable<float> Query ( IEnumerable<float> original ) {
    IEnumerable<float> result = original;
    foreach ( var i in rules ) {
        result = result.Where( i.where ).Select( i.select );
    }
    return result;
}

rules.AddRange( new[] {
    ( (x => true), (x => x + 2) ),
    ( (x => x < 50), (x => x) ),
    ( (x => true), (x => x * 3) ),
    ( (x => true), (x => x * 10) ),
    ( (x => true), (x => ( x > 999 ) ? 999 : x) )
} );
```

or even better:

```cs
List<Func<IEnumerable<float>,IEnumerable<float>>> rules;

public IEnumerable Query ( IEnumerable<float> original ) {
    foreach ( var i in rules ) original = i.Invoke( original );
    return original;
}

rules.AddRange( new[] {
    ( x => x.Select( y => y + 2 ) ),
    ( x => x.Where( y => y < 50 ) ),
    ( x => x.Select( y => y * 3 ) ),
    ( x => x.Select( y => y * 10 ) ),
    ( x => x.Select( y => ( y > 999 ) ? 999 : y ) ),
} );
```